# how to insert data from scrapy to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

i am trying to get data from amazon using scrapy i can get data in CSV but i am not able to insert data in mysql database
please find my code
**my spider is**

```
import scrapy
from craigslist_sample.items import AmazonDepartmentItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class AmazonAllDepartmentSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_sad/187-3757581-3331414"
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = AmazonDepartmentItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        return item
```

**my pipeline code is**

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):


    host = 'rerhr.com'
    user = 'amazon'
    password = 'sads23'
    db = 'amazon_project'

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.db)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):   
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO amazon_project.ProductDepartment (ProductDepartmentLilnk) 
                            VALUES (%s)""",
                           (
                            item['link'].encode('utf-8')))

            self.connection.commit()

        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        return item
```

when i run following command

scrapy crawl amazon -o items.csv -t csv

then i can able to get data in my CSV
but when i run

scrapy crawl amazon

with above code i am not able to insert data in mysql
[image]
so please help me what we have to do then i can insert data in mysql

thanks

Comment: What is on the console? Any errors? Is pipeline turned on in settings? Are you sure you are checking results into the same database you are inserting in? Thanks.

Comment: my pipeline setting is ITEM_PIPELINES = ['projectname.pipelines.MySQLStorePipeline'] and yes i am checking same database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is actually inside the `parse()` callback. `extract()` calls **return a list** and, as a result, all item field values become lists. Then, `item['link'].encode('utf-8')` call in the pipeline fails because there is no `encode()` method on a list.

A quick and simple fix would be to get the first elements of the `extract()` call results:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        item = AmazonDepartmentItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()[0]
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()[0]
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
        yield item
```

Note that I've also replaced the `return item` expression with a `yield item` and put it inside the loop.

---

A better approach would be to define an [`ItemLoader`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with *input and output processors*:

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst

class ProductLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

FYI, here is what [`TakeFirst()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.TakeFirst) does:

> Returns the first non-null/non-empty value from the values received,
>   so it’s typically used as an output processor to single-valued fields.
>   It doesn’t receive any constructor arguments, nor accept Loader
>   contexts.

Then, the `parse()` method would transform into:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        l = ItemLoader(item=AmazonDepartmentItem(), selector=sel)
        l.add_xpath('title', 'a/text()')
        l.add_xpath('link', 'a/@href')
        l.add_xpath('desc', 'text()')
        yield l.load_item()
```